# How can I download Unreal Engine 3

Tags: game-engine

I am very interested in game development and I want to learn Unreal Engine 3. I am not going to use it for commerical purposes therefore I am wondering if it is free for students. I don't know where I can go about downloading and finding easy resources for learning it. I also would like to know if there any easy way to learn game development. I already know Flash and know how to create 2D games. But now I am very interested in learning how to create 3D games like Call of Duty and so on. I wonder what applications companies like EA, Activision, Blizzard and so on use to create games.

Comment: This question should have been moved to http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/. It should not have been closed.

Answer (score 3):

The Website of the Unreal Development Kit (UDK) provides a download and documentation: http://www.udk.com/

Especially this might be interesting for you: [Getting Started Overview](http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/GettingStartedOverview.html).

Answer (score 2):

These folks may be better equipped to help you:

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Good luck!